# Protobuf-net interop with Java UUID and C# Guid

Tags: java, c#, guid, uuid, protobuf-net

So protobuf-net uses this proto content for a .NET guid:

```
message Guid {
  optional fixed64 lo = 1; // the first 8 bytes of the guid
  optional fixed64 hi = 2; // the second 8 bytes of the guid
}
```

...and when I compile that proto into Java classes and create this Java UUID instance:

```
UUID uid = UUID.fromString("2ac9f438-f555-40b0-8880-02226b81285c");
```

...then it doesn't matter whether I use uid.getMostSignificantBits() or uid.getLeastSignificantBits() as the argument to Guid.setHi() ( or Guid.setLo() ).

No matter which combination I choose, when C# deserializes the type containing the Java-generated guid, and I test the value of the guid, I get what appears to be byte ordering problems:

```
expected:<2ac9f438-f555-40b0-8880-02226b81285c>
 but was:<f55540b0-f438-2ac9-5c28-816b22028088>
```

...or:

```
expected:<2ac9f438-f555-40b0-8880-02226b81285c>
 but was:<6b81285c-0222-8880-b040-55f538f4c92a>
```

Is there a simple fix for this problem?

Should point out that I'm new to protobuf, so a little hazy on possibilities here.

**EDIT:**

For what it's worth, I've also tried Long.reverseBytes() on the result of one or both uid.getLeast/MostSignificantBits() before providing the result to Guid.setLo/Hi, and swapping those orders as well, but alas...

**EDIT, the second:**
No wonder simple byte-order swapping on the two longs doesn't work (excerpted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)):

> The order of the beginning four-byte group and the next two two-byte
>   groups is reversed, whereas the order of the last two-byte group and
>   the closing six-byte group is the same.

See my answer posted to this question for one possibility.  Not sure there's really any other way, if both languages are to use their native binary guid/uuid types in application code.  Any other suggestions (besides sending guid's as strings)?

Comment: I found out, way too late, that Guid uses what I can only describe as "crazy endianness"

Comment: @MarcGravell - fwiw so far, I've enjoyed working with protobuf-net toolchain more than the corresponding tools for java.  Round-tripping is simple, elegant, and low friction for app integration, which hasn't been the case in my experience so far with the java protobuf tools. I suppose interop requirements will chuck a wrench into some language's works somewhere along the line.  But, all said, hats off to protobuf-net!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so one workaround for this is to first define the C# class that contains the Guid such that the Guid type does not participate in serialization/deserialization, but to use a byte array instead.  This might look something like so:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Entity
{
    private bool _idInitialized = false;
    private Guid _id;

    public Guid id
    {
        get
        {
            if ( !_idInitialized )
            {
                _id = new Guid( idBytes );
                _idInitialized = true;
            }

            return _id;
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember( 1, IsRequired = true )]
    public byte[] idBytes;

    [ProtoMember( 2, IsRequired = true )]
    public String name;

    // For application code, sending side
    public Entity( Guid theId, String theName )
    {
        if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( theName ) )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "theName" );
        }

        idBytes = theId.ToByteArray();
        _id = theId;
        _idInitialized = true;
        name = theName;
    }

    // For protobuf-net, receiving side
    public Entity() { }
}
```

Then generate the proto file for the type using GetProto:

```
Serializer.GetProto<Entity>()
```

Which produces this:

```
message Entity {
   required bytes idBytes = 1;
   required string name = 2;
}
```

Compile this to Java classes using protoc.  I put together a wrapper class that uses the generated protobuf classes internally.  This wrapper class uses the conversion methods below to reorder bytes on the way in and out on behalf of the wrapper class.  ByteBuffer and Apache Commons' ArrayUtils.reverse() did all the work.

If interop with another language is needed, a similar approach could be used.  Every language would just conform to the .NET byte ordering scheme via some equivalent utilities for that language.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class Utilities {

    public static UUID getUuidFromDotNetGuidBytes(byte[] guidBytes) {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(guidBytes);

        byte[] first4 = new byte[4];
        bb.get(first4);
        ArrayUtils.reverse( first4 );

        byte[] second2 = new byte[2];
        bb.get(second2);
        ArrayUtils.reverse( second2 );

        byte[] third2 = new byte[2];
        bb.get(third2);
        ArrayUtils.reverse( third2 );

        long lsb = bb.getLong();

        bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8]);
        bb.put( first4 );
        bb.put( second2 );
        bb.put( third2 );

        bb.rewind();
        long msb = bb.getLong();

        return new UUID(msb, lsb);
    }

    public static byte[] getDotNetGuidBytes(UUID theUuid) {

        ByteBuffer first8 = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        first8.putLong(theUuid.getMostSignificantBits());
        first8.rewind();

        byte[] first4 = new byte[4];
        first8.get(first4);
        ArrayUtils.reverse( first4 );

        byte[] second2 = new byte[2];
        first8.get(second2);
        ArrayUtils.reverse( second2 );

        byte[] third2 = new byte[2];
        first8.get(third2);
        ArrayUtils.reverse( third2 );

        ByteBuffer converted16 = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
        converted16.put(first4);
        converted16.put(second2);
        converted16.put(third2);

        ByteBuffer last8 = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        last8.putLong(theUuid.getLeastSignificantBits());        
        last8.rewind();

        converted16.put(last8);

        return converted16.array();
    }

}
```