# Serialize data in a language agnostic way while preserving Guid type

Tags: java, c#, serialization

I have a C# api that receives some data in format `Dictionary<string, object>` where
object can be either string, Guid or array of string or Guid.

The caller of this api is going to be a Java application. Is there a way to serialize such a collection in a way that C# will be able to deserialize and correctly identify which values are Guids.

Comment: Java has no Guid type (but does have UUIDv4) so I suggest just keeping data as strings. What data types does the **API accept**? JSON? XML? Protobuf over gRPC? All of those are language agnostic

Comment: I have control over both ends of this. The thing that I want is for java serializer to put a hint into the seriazlied object so that C# desirializer will know to differentiate string from guid.

Comment: I am not well versed in C# serialization libraries, but if you pass a UUIDv4 as a string, are you able to get a GUID? If so, then JSON at the very least will work. There is an old answer here for protobuf - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417127/protobuf-net-interop-with-java-uuid-and-c-sharp-guid